# Syntax error when using parentheses instead of brackets

Tags: racket

I thought that [brackets and parentheses were interchangeable](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-pair%29) in Racket.

However, when I run the following code, I get the syntax error, `else: not allowed as an expression in: (else (cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat))))`

```lisp
#lang racket

(define rember
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) (quote ()))
      ((eq? a (car lat) (cdr lat))
      (else
        (cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat))))))))
```

The error goes away when I replace the parentheses in `cond` with brackets:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define rember
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      [(null? lat) (quote ())]
      [(eq? a (car lat)) (cdr lat)]
      [else
        (cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat)))])))
```

So it appears that there is a syntactic difference between parentheses and brackets.  Is this the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot one parenthesis in `((eq? a (car lat) (cdr lat))`. If you rewrite that correctly, both versions will work:

```
(define rember
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) (quote ()))
      ((eq? a (car lat)) (cdr lat))
      (else
        (cons (car lat) (rember a (cdr lat)))))))
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense.  I should've known to look there if it was complaining about the `else`.  Thank you